# how to change the default operation of SD card when it is inserted into the slot

Tags: linux, usb, android

Please show me the way to do it on Linux. And what's the default permission of it when it is loaded from an android. Currently the directory /mnt/sdcard can be neither viewed nor entered. So I guess there's some trick here

Comment: Let me get the question right. You are trying to access the sdcard of your mobile on Linux?

Comment: yes @VishnuPrasadKallummel

Comment: The sdcard is write protected if you are trying to access the sdcard directly by placing the sdcard into a card reader. What is the file system of the sdcard?

Comment: No the sdcard is in a Android Phone. I was able to access it before, but all of suddent, I was locked out of it. How to view the filesystem of my sdcard?

Comment: Do you have a windows system to check?

Comment: yes. I have windows

Comment: seems like a CDFS?

Comment: CDFS? That's weird. It should most probably be FAT/FAT32 then linux would recognize it. Did you check by mounting in windows?